# quotaExceeded 403 error on Google Search Console APIs

Tags: php, api, google-api-php-client, google-search-api

I am using Google's php client library to add sites(urls) to my search console account. After `1000 urls`, I am getting `403 client errors` saying the `quota is exceeded`.

My quota in the search console account is 2000requests/ 100seconds/ user. I am giving some delay between the requests so I wont hit the quota limit. I used batch request to submit the urls. Whatever the delay between the batch requests, I am getting quotaExceeded errors after 1000 url submissions.

How to solve this ?

Comment: have you tried to add a random number to QuotaUser? https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/parameters

Comment: @DalmTo I tried adding quotaUser to the constructor of Google client and while using the sites resource but not working. Could you help on how to do this.

Comment: hey have you figured out how to add the quotaUser to the google client ?

Answer (score 0):

I was using the add site api for the wrong purpose. Add sites is to the domain url not a page url. We can add the page urls to crawl from the search console web user interface but its different from the add sites.

May be, to have more than 1000 domains is an error.